# Can Eclipse debugging trace loaded Java libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Morning all.

I work on maintaining a complex Java application that uses dozens of megabytes of third-party libraries. Recently I've been working on isolating a part of it to run as a standalone application, which by and large depends on the same source files as its parent. It's basically one complex wizard dialog from the original application, which still exists in the original application and which I don't want to maintain twice.

Installed alongside the whole application, the standalone part works fine. But now I want to make a standalone distribution. The part I've isolated still needs some third-party libraries, but I don't know which ones. Many of the classes involved have multipurpose constructors that can take some complex UI objects from the original application, and all the libraries that make them work have to be there at compile-time, but the execution path will be sharply curtailed at run-time.

Is there some way that I can configure Eclipse to monitor which libraries are being loaded during debugging? Either a plugin or some core functionality I've missed?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you're pulling it out as a new project on its own, have you considered using a dependency management system like Maven for the new project?

Comment: Can't you determine which libraries you need by looking at method calls, varialbes, etc.? If you have only your application part without the external libraries, you'll get compiler errors for missing references. Then find these references.

Comment: @Brian - Dependency management isn't the answer here. I'm looking at which third-party libraries the complex central application depends on, not how libraries chain into each other.

Comment: @user1803551 - Right, I've clarified what I'm trying to do here. Short version, I need a lot more libraries at compile time than I do at run time.

Comment: I don't understand how you need less libraries at runtime than at compile-time. If you don't have all the classes you need for compilation then you don't have all the classes you need for running. Maybe you mean that *you don't use* classes at runtime which are being compiled?

Comment: @user1803551 - Yes. Like I edited to say, I'm still using parts of the original application which are intended to be multipurpose and can take some very complex objects, but I'm never going to be calling those constructors that way in the standalone, so I don't need whatever third-party libraries support those objects.

Comment: Then do what I first suggested. Copy the part of the "central application" you want as a standalone, see what references are missing, where they are declared in external libraries, and copy those libraries to your application. You can use `Open Call Hierarchy` and `Open Type Hierarchy` in eclipse's context menu to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63054/discussion-between-glazius-and-user1803551).